# How can I allow user create a powerpoint presentation on my site?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, powerpoint

I want to allow users of a site I am building to create a powerpoint presentation through my site. I need them to be able to edit them and download them also. I want to do this over a site for reasons of version control.

I have tried the Google Drive implementation and its very good, can this be integrated with a php site?

Thanks

Comment: Is this even related to google-app-engine?

Answer (score 1):

This is can be done using third party libraries.  You can find out about these libraries through googling.  One library that claims to do the job is 
[PHP PowerPoint 2007 classes](http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks John, but its now 2014 and I know how to use Google, 2007 is 7 years ago and not relevant to today.

Comment: PowerPoint 2007 and onward share the same file format.  A solution that works for 2007 is most certainly relevant to today.

Comment: Responding sarcastically to a helpful (and correct!) answer is poor netiquette.